# MessageBox shown after function is over

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a javascript function that calls my javascript function, my func islike this:

```
function sugParitValidation(){
   var isValid = false;
   Ext.MessageBox.confirm('  ','Are you sure you want to do this?',  function(btn){
      if(btn == 'yes'){
      isValid = true;
    }
 });
 return isValid ;
}
```

My problem is - if statement and the return statment is happening, and only after that the confirm window being shown.
That way I can't react to what the user choosed.
how to solve this? tried allready use setTimeOut, no change at all....

Comment: Try `window.confirm()` . This statment will block till user response.

Comment: You have there a callback that is called when the user clicks on the confirm buttons. You can't wait until the user presses a button because you will block the entire UI. You can return a promise or pass another callback to sugParitValidation() method and call it when the user clicks a button in order to continue the flow.

Comment: window.confirm() isn't good for me because i have to use extjs style. I'll probably make a call function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are trying to do something like this.

```
someFunction(){
     if(sugParitValidation()){
          //todo something
     }
     else{
          //todo another thing
     }

}
```

you can do this easyly with callbacks. This is the example.

```
someFunction(){
     var messageCallback = function(btn){
          if(btn === 'yes'){
               //todo something
          }
          else{
              //todo another thing
          }

     }
     Ext.MessageBox.confirm('  ','Are you sure you want to do this?', 
     messageCallback);
}
```