# Ext JS correct event flow

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, datagrid, sencha-architect

I want the user to confirm he will click on another item on grid without saving the changes on the last one by capturing the `beforeselect` event. The problem is that I show the `messageBox` for users confirmation but the event executes to the end, before the user can confirm. Is there any way to block the event until the user makes a choice ?

```
onGridBeforeSelect() {
  Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Delete', 'Are you sure ?', function(btn){
   if(btn === 'yes'){
      return true; //will execute select event
   }
   else{
      return false; //woun't execute select event
   }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some flag that indicates the need of the confirmation, if it is needed return false, and then if confirmed select it again, like:

```
function onGridBeforeSelect(grid, record) {
  if (grid.isConfirmed){
    return;
  }

  Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Delete', 'Are you sure ?', function(btn){
   if(btn === 'yes'){
      grid.isConfirmed = true;
      grid.setSelection(record);
      grid.isConfirmed = false;
   }

   return false;
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the flag method is not elagant way to do this. This question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411085/messagebox-shown-after-function-is-over/33493033) before and i answered like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33493033/5201640).